# Facebook Session Not Setting

Tags: facebook

I have used Facebook Connect to Login in my site and Currently I m not logged in  and my Facebook account is logged in another tab so when I goes to our site I dont get the Facebook Session i.e. when I print $facebook->getUser() I got 0.
SO can anyone please help me put what I can do for it.
I always get the active access token error

Answer (score 0):

When you have not logged in your application the application will return 0 with

```
$facebook->getUser()
```

this is because user has not logged in the application, to get the user you have to either redirect user to login URL or ask user to login by clicking on url provided by:-

```
$facebook->getLoginUrl()
```